# Harmonic analysis of an electrical circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, harmonics

I am having troubles trying to figure this out.
I have a complicated electrical circuit and I would like to compute the spectrum of some voltages of interest. Below is an example of what I want to do on a simpler circuit [image: simpler circuit]. My two voltages of interest here are those in red. V1 and V2: [image: V1] [image: enter V2]V2 which could be computed easily as in the pictures. Where Vi is the spectrum of the input voltage and Zc is the impedance of the circuit which could be computed using an .ac analysis in LTSpice. Values (or rather the vectors -harmonics-) V1 and V2 could be computed using Matlab or python.
My question is the following: For very complicated circuits, pen-and-paper is basically impossible, do you guys have an suggestions on how I can go about it?

PS: All the parameters (R1,Cm1,L1,etc...) are frequency dependent. I have fitted them and deduced their rational approximations.

Happy new year and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118066/discussion-on-question-by-wallflower-harmonic-analysis-of-an-electrical-circuit).

Comment: The other Falstad site does FFT in “real” Time but slow motion and only linear scale. But what signal? You can float a scope trace of any part or wire and view V, I or P and export, import a 12th order Bessel Filter for e.g.